# When I use sql, I do get deprecated warning

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, deprecated, yahoo-finance

I am confused. I get a warning when I switch the order of the code.

**First version:**

```
from trial import beta

from cs50 import SQL
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")

symbol = 'AAPL'
bet = beta(symbol)
id = 14

db.execute("UPDATE portfolio SET beta=:beta WHERE id=:id AND symbol=:symbol", beta=bet, id=id, symbol=symbol)
```

*Error:*

DeprecationWarning: UrlOpener style of invoking requests is deprecated. Use newer urlopen functions/methods

**Version 2:**

```
from trial import beta

from cs50 import SQL


symbol = 'AAPL'
bet = beta(symbol)
id = 14

db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")
db.execute("UPDATE portfolio SET beta=:beta WHERE id=:id AND symbol=:symbol", beta=bet, id=id, symbol=symbol)
```

*Result:*

UPDATE portfolio SET beta='1.11' WHERE id=14 AND symbol='AAPL'

The reason that I am concerned is that I want to use the output as a function but whenever I try, even though I change the order I get the same error in my main application.

Any tips for this python newbie?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Python do you use? URLopener is deprecated since version 3.3. For more information, please check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html).